# Where is this strange code coming from in my php/mysql app and how do I get rid of it

Tags: php, mysql, html, tinymce

Last week, Thursday to be exact, the autogen php/mysql web form we have has a textarea field where we use tinyMCE to allow client to input and format their text.  Suddenly on Thursday the text would not appear in the form, along with the border that surrounds the textarea data in display mode, but when we went to the edit screen where the tinyMCE field is, we could see the text.  I came in today and looked at the db and see all this odd code in the db [see below]

I have overwritten the code with straight, clean text, load the page it work, but then it eventually reverts to this odd code-- and at some point you refresh your browser and no longer see any text from the php form.  When I look in the db again, all this code[see below]is back in the field.

I been surfing/researching and various suggestions include updating tinyMCE, which I did, but same things happens.

Does anyone have any idea what I should do, what part of the code to attack, is it the db or the tinyMCE?  All help is much appreciated. [Note: app has been running successfully for about 2 years.]

```
> <p><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <o:OfficeDocumentSettings> <o:AllowPNG />
> </o:OfficeDocumentSettings> </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
> <w:WordDocument> <w:View>Normal</w:View> <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
> <w:TrackMoves /> <w:TrackFormatting /> <w:PunctuationKerning />
> <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas />
> <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
> <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
> <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
> <w:DoNotPromoteQF />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY! FINALLY discovered what was wrong - there is a size limitation for the amount of data stored in the session object. And as per RFC 2109 this size limit is 4KB. That was it. I knew I was hitting some limit somewhere, finally figured it out where it was. Had to re-write some code so I could pull only these text section and not rely on the data stored in the session.

Answer (score 3):

This is what happens when people copy and paste direct from word into TinyMCE, nothing more sinister than that.

Comment: The problem is, that you can't explain to the people who did so, why that would be a problem...

Comment: But, when I go back into the web form and add plain text, no formatting, the field data resets to include all this code.  So for example, if I type "This is a test", click save, look at form, "This is test" will appear.  When I refresh the browser, clear cache, all that funky code above appear again and somewhere near the bottom of it, embedded in it, I will see "This is a test", but nothing now appears on the display page.  I have gone directly into the db, added straight test, refreshed the db, looked at the form, see the straight test, then I refresh and that plague of code is back.

Comment: TinyMCE, even if it seems to be completely empty, sometimes keeps old markup. If you do Load page / manually remove text in the graphical UI / type something new / save - then yes, you will keep all this weird markup. If you do / load page / edit source and remove everything / add new text / save, then you will have clean markup, I'm almost certain.

Comment: In researching I found issues with copy/paste in tinyMCE, so in a desperate move, took the clients' text and re-typed it in, adding no formatting. Got to the 7th paragraph, saved everything, went back to the form to view, nothing from the textarea field would display.  There is even a border around this section, it would not display. Went back to the db, all the text is still there, but will not display on the form. Are there some textarea limitations I'm not aware of?  I up'd the column rows to 30, changed db field type to **mediumtext**. Still, I get to a certain point, nothing displays.

Comment: Have you got the 'view source' button on your tinyMCE?

Comment: There's no weirdness going on with the textareas. TinyMCE does do validation on the markup entered, which can cause issues (tries to close tags etc).

Answer (score 0):

You should check the interface between tinymce and your db to find out if the data comes directly from tinymce that way or if the data gets modified on the way to the db.

Btw., the wierd code looks like HTML generated from Word.

Comment: Thanks Thariama and u r correct, it was MS generated madness.  I tried something else, see note above.

Comment: right before you submit your form (is it per ajax?) call the following using firebug or an other web developer tool:  alert(tinymce.get('my_editor_id').getContent({format : 'raw'}));. Please tell me what you get.

Comment: hum, not ajax, but I think I can still do this.  Let me try.  Back in a bit.

Comment: Ok, I hope I am getting close.  I ran my debugger for the 100th time and saw, the var that is holding the intro text [session->userdata->ACCOUNT_INTRO_TEXT] saids 1024 (2963) for length.

Comment: FINALLY! FINALLY discovered what was wrong -  there is a size limitation for the amount of data stored in the session object.  And as per RFC 2109 this size limit is 4KB.  That was it.  I knew I was hitting some limit somewhere, finally figured it out where it was. Had to re-write some code so I could pull only these text section and not rely on the data stored in the session.